# ClassNotFoundException when loading local Symfony bundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I try to install a custom Symfony bundle in my application.
I created the bundle with the following folder structure:

```
.
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
└── src
    └── Namespace
        └── CoreBundle
            ├── Controller ...
            ├── CoreBundle.php
            ├── Entity ...
            ├── Helper ...
            ├── Repository ...
            ├── Resources ...
            ├── Services ...
            └── Tests ...
```

I successfully installed the bundle by `composer install` in the `vendor` folder. There it is under `vendor/namespace/core-bundle` as a sym-link (I loaded it locally).

After that I added `new Namespace\CoreBundle\CoreBundle(),` in the `AppKernel.php` and this produces the following error:

```
(1/1) ClassNotFoundException

Attempted to load class "CoreBundle" from namespace "Namespace\CoreBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
in AppKernel.php (line 25)
```

I tried to copy the folder manually in `vendor` folder, if there is any problem with the sym-link, but it produces the same error. I checked out the autoloaded classes by `dump(ClassMapGenerator::createMap('/path/to/symfony'));` and I don't found my namespace there. Is my configuration wrong or my folder structure? If you need more code, I'll update my question as fast as possible.

**Update:** My bundles `composer.json`:

```
{
  "name": "namespace/core-bundle",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "type": "symfony-bundle",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Namespace\\CoreBundle\\": "src/Namespace/CoreBundle"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "1.9.*",
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
  },
  "extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "development"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to post your CoreBundles `composer.json`.

Comment: I added the `composer.json`.

Comment: Shouldn't it say `"Namespace\\CoreBundle\\": "src/"` in the autoload psr-4 part? Edit: nvm - was thinking psr-0. Does it work after you manually dump the autoloader using `composer dump-autoload -a` ?

Comment: Thanks! `composer dump-autoload -a` did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After every manual update of `autoload` section in your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Namespace\\CoreBundle\\": "src/Namespace/CoreBundle"
        }
    }
}
```

**don't forget to refresh** your generated `/vendor/autoload.php` via CLI:

```
composer dump 
# shortcut for `composer dump-autoload`
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that you have run `composer install` before adding the autoload in your autoload in the `composer.json`. the problem with this, is that install ignores the .json file, and goes straight for the lock file, and the lock stores all the previous dependencies, leaving it in a previously tested state.

What you are looking for is `composer update`. It discards .lock file, and generates a new .lock file for future install commands.

Comment: I manually deleted the `.lock` file and ran `composer update` but the problem persists. :(

Comment: do you have `require('path/to/vendor/autoload.php')` in your entry script?

Comment: Thank you for your help. `composer dump-autoload -a` did the trick.